# How to solve syntax error involving sqlite row storage of msg.author.id from discord?

Tags: javascript, sqlite, discord.js

I'm trying to build an interface for Discord using Node.js 8x, MVS 2017, Discord.js, and sqlite + sqlite3. The desired result is for the bot to send a message to the channel that states: "@Maverick has already accepted the daily rewards". However I keep getting "@Maverick has been gifted 200 glimmer" I've built the scores table with my own user data by utilizing the JADE addon for google chrome just to double check what might be going on. I've manually stored my userID but this didn't change the results. I believe that the sqlite code is ignoring the msg.author.id all together. Instead I need it to store the data so that it can be checked in the future. I'm a begining programmer and used the following site for the basis of this code: [Discord.js Bot Guide](https://anidiotsguide.gitbooks.io/discord-js-bot-guide/coding-guides/storing-data-in-an-sqlite-file.html)

With the code posted below, I am getting the following error: 
`UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 4): Error: SQLITE_ERROR: near "WHERE": syntax error`

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const bot = new Discord.Client();
const sql = require("sqlite");
sql.open("./score.sqlite");
const prefix = "!"    
bot.on("message", function (msg) {
    if (msg.content.toLowerCase() === prefix + "dailies") { // Dailies Function
        // I believe that the error is triggered in the next line: 
        var dailyCheck = sql.get(`SELECT daily FROM scores WHERE userId ="${msg.author.id}"`);
        sql.run("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS scores (userId TEXT, daily INTEGER, glimmer INTEGER, wr INTEGER, rotw INTEGER)").then(row => {
            if (dailyCheck === 1) {
                msg.channel.send('<@${msg.author.id}> has already accepted the daily rewards! Try again after the daily reset (2:00 AM PST) to claim again.');
            } 
        });
    }
});
```

[SQLite Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8qavC.png)

Comment: What does your table schema look like? Also, I *think* you're supposed to have a semicolon at the end of the statement with SQLLite.

Comment: It's a table. I believe I have a semicolon at the end of both sql functions so could you provide more information?

Comment: I've got no idea as to why this was happening, but I rebuilt the code and it doesn't happen anymore. Thank you everyone for stopping by. My only suggestion would be to edit borrowed code as little as possible to ensure it keeps working properly.